# Are there any OpenGL ES 2.0 examples for JOGL?

Tags: jogl, opengl-es2

I've scoured the internet for the last few hours looking for an example of how to run even the most basic OpenGL ES 2 example using JOGL but "by Jupiter!" it has been a total fail.

I tried converting the android example from the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/) examples (and at the same time looking at the WebGL example -- which worked fine) yet without any success.

Are there any examples out there?

---

If anyone else wants some extra help regarding this question see [this](http://forum.jogamp.org/GL2ES2-implementation-td3270403.html#a3277843) thread on the official Jogamp forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book "[Guide to Graphics Software Tools](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849968004)" uses JOGL to his examples. There are examples for shaders in GLSL, HLSL and Cg.

**Edited**

In http://www.davidcornette.com/glsl/download.html there are examples with source code.
http://www.guyford.co.uk/index.php/forum/14-java-jogl/15-jogl-example-glsl-shader-setup has a bit of code.

Comment: I had a look at that book; it's not really what I'm looking for (plus it is pretty pricey considering I only want _one_ example). I already have the book I mentioned in my question so it's just a matter of getting something running so that I can continue learning.

Comment: Ok. I've edited my answer with links to examples.

Answer (score 2):

Xerxes Ranby contributed [a raw ES2 demo](http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl-demos.git;a=blob;f=src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java;hb=HEAD), not using any JOGL utilities
and is self contained.

Then you can have a look at [another simple demo code](http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl-demos.git;a=blob;f=src/demos/es2/RedSquare.java;hb=HEAD) 
using some JOGL utilities. Of course, here you would need
to check the shader files.

Comment: If I had at least 15 points I'd upvote your answer. Thanks for the examples.